# How to compare one document to all other in a dataset using spacy document similarity function?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have a requirement to compare a document with all others in the dataset and get the similarity score. I am using spacy's similarity function to do this. As the no.of documents in the dataset are 10^6 the brute-force approach using 2 for loops is taking a very long time? Is there any direct method to achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated

```
import uuid
import time
start_time=time.time()
counter = 1
similar_desc_uuid_dict_o=dict()
for doc1 in descs[:2]:
    uniqueid=str(uuid.uuid4())
    if counter % 1 == 0:
        print("Processed %d out of %d documents." % (counter, len(descs)))
    counter+=1
    for doc2 in descs:
        if(doc1.similarity(doc2)>=0.89):
            current_value=similar_desc_uuid_dict_o.get(str(doc2))
            if(current_value==None):
                similar_desc_uuid_dict_o[str(doc2)]=uniqueid
            else:
                updated_value=current_value+" "+uniqueid
                similar_desc_uuid_dict_o[str(doc2)]=updated_value
print('Done. Time elapsed: {:.2f}mins'.format((time.time() - start_time)/60))

similar_desc_uuid_dict_o
```

Comment: Perhaps you could build a graph as you go. You could avoid doing a lot of checks that way. For example, if d1 and d2 have a similarity of 0.1, while d2 and d3 have a similarity of 0.9, there is almost no chance that d1 and d3 will be similar enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to perform the above task at scale using a gensim.
here is my working code:

```
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary
from gensim.models import TfidfModel, LsiModel
from gensim.similarities import Similarity
from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile
import sys
import time, traceback

def cossim(documents, query_docs=None, task='pairwise_similarity', metric_threshold=0.85, num_best=20, **kwargs):
    try:
        dictionary = Dictionary(documents)
        tfidf = TfidfModel(dictionary=dictionary)
        corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in documents]
        features_rep='bow'
        if len(dictionary) > 1000 and len(dictionary) <=2000:
            corpus = [tfidf[doc] for doc in corpus]
            features_rep='tfidf'
        elif len(dictionary) > 2000:
            model = LsiModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=200)
            corpus = [model[tfidf[doc]] for doc in corpus]
            features_rep = 'lsi'
        index_tmpfile = get_tmpfile("index")
        index = Similarity(output_prefix=index_tmpfile, corpus=corpus, num_best=num_best, num_features=len(dictionary),
                           chunksize=256)
        similarities = []
        if task == 'pairwise_similarity':
            start_time = time.time()

            for sim in index:
                similarities.append(sim)

        elif task == 'batch_query':
            start_time = time.time()
            query_docs_features = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in query_docs]
            if features_rep=='tfidf':
                query_docs_features = [tfidf[doc] for doc in query_docs_features]
            elif features_rep=='lsi':
                query_docs_features = [model[tfidf[doc]] for doc in query_docs_features]
            for sim in index[query_docs_features]:
                similarities.append(sim)
        filtered_results = []
        for ind_sim in similarities:
            filtered_results.append([item[0] for item in ind_sim if item[1] >= metric_threshold])
        if query_docs is not None:
            matched_docs, unmatched_docs, matching_stats = stats(documents, query_docs, filtered_results)
            return matched_docs, unmatched_docs
        else:
            return filtered_results
    except Exception:
        logging.error(
            "Exception has occurred while performing Cosine Similarity. {}".format(traceback.format_exc()))
```